# How to know whether the phone is locked mode?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-intent, lockscreen

Is there a way for me to know whether the phone is in locked state?

Answer (score 1):

Have your app listen our for the `ACTION_SCREEN_OFF` broadcast. More information [here](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/handling-screen-off-and-screen-on-intents/).

```
public class ScreenReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {     

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
                //screen locked                
            } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
                //screen unlocked   
            }
        }

}
```

You might also want to receive information of when the user gets past the keyguard by registering for the [ACTION_USER_PRESENT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_USER_PRESENT) broadcast.

Comment: Not working the reason is   http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SCREEN_ON  just see there those are protected intents Can be sent only by system. Please post if you have any other alternative