# turn wifi on/off when phone screen lock(sleep)

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-manifest

Heloo all
im new to android
and im trying to create an application that turn the wifi off when the screen lock
and enable the wifi every spacific time to fetch data and turn it off again
while the phone in lock screen

i know how to 
1)set the Timer 
2)how to enable Wifi
3)disable Wifi

but i need to know how to listen to the lock screen event
so when the screen locked my code will start.

any help plzz?

Comment: Read it from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6011166/how-to-know-whether-the-phone-is-locked-mode/6011280#6011280

Comment: i put this in mainfest  <receiver android:name="ScreenLockReceiver">
   <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
   </intent-filter>
  </receiver>     but nothing happend but if i use the ACTION_USER_PRESENT the broadcastReceiver is called !!!

Answer (score 0):

To detect screen wake, set a BroadcastRecever [ACTION_SCREEN_ON](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SCREEN_ON). To detect screen unlock, use ACTION_USER_PRESENT.

1. Use AlarmManager if you need your code to be run at scheduled intervals.
2. Use WifiManager. Permissions are needed.

Comment: i made broadcastreciver but the class is initilized only of i lock the screen while my apps is running on foreground, if i pressed the home button so the app is working in background , and pressed lock screen, my code will not be called

Comment: and im using emulator not reall device, so idk why the action screen on /off are not fired!!

Comment: Try ACTION_USER_PRESENT which fires when screen lock is unlocked.

Comment: Also note that paused Activities do not receive Broadcasts. You should use Service.

Comment: check this plz   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7366631/action-screen-on-action-screen-off-not-working